# Angular jasmine find hanging timers

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a test that fails randomly with error that `fixture.isStable()` expected to be true and `5 timer(s) still in the queue.` although I've tried to increase `tick` value to 1s it doesn't seem to have a needed effect.

I know that I can pass time by very huge amount of time or kill this timers, but I'd rather find these timers. Analysis of used components and modules didn't give me any clue since they don't have any `setTimeout` or `delay`s or similar.

Is there a way to find what these timers are and perhaps where they were started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've tried `flush` instead of `tick` and when I started tests it turned out that one of the connected components deep inside injected a service which was using webpack's `import` and was failing on it.

Only after using `flush` chunk load error has revealed itself.